# Separate Content from gallery (custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, gallery, the-content

i have a php file (single-model.php) who display in one div first the post content and than the gallery in thumbs.

How can split the content from gallery and display the gallery in diferent div ..?

the code is this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"> 

<?php the_content();

    $ids = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'scent_model_photos', true );

    $selected_images = '';

    if( !empty($ids) ) {

        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {

            $selected_images .= $key . ',';

        }

    }

    echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="3" size="model-gallery" link="file" ids="' . $selected_images . '"]'); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<section id="content">

    <div class="container">

        <?php get_template_part('inc/page-title'); ?>

        <div class="row">

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-7 post-thumb large-thumbnail">

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('model-full', array( 'class' => "img-responsive" )); ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-5 entry-content profile">

                        <?php $properties = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'scent_model_data_repeat_group', true);

                                    if (!empty($properties)) {   ?>

                            <ul class="profile">

                            <?php foreach ($properties as $value) {    ?>

                                <li class="row">

                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3"><strong><?php echo $value['title']; ?></strong></div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-9"><?php echo $value['value']; ?></div>

                                </li>

                            <?php } ?>

                            </ul>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <?php the_content();

                    $ids = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'scent_model_photos', true);
                    $selected_images = '';

                    if (!empty($ids)) {
                        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
                            $selected_images .= $key . ',';
                        }
                    }

                            ?>

                        </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                      <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="3" size="model-gallery" link="file" ids="<?php echo $selected_images; ?>"]'); ?>

                    </div>

                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php scent_paging_nav(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part('content', 'none'); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Nope. :( not work..

Comment: What didn't work ? what is the error ? is there any log about it ? please try to explain why is not working

Comment: Ok, here is the error that print me in page

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpget_header() in /home/****/public_html/******/wp-content/themes/scent/single-model.php on line 1

Comment: Where do you see "phpget_header() " on my code ? my code is working and is tested

Comment: you can not find "phpget_header() " on my code, can you ?

Comment: Here is all the php file (single-model.php).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4JG3LmxT

Comment: @DemetrisLyngas I have updated the code above for you